# VB.NET ERROR WHEN USING My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText Into thread

Tags: vb.net

i got this error ({"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."}) when i try to use  My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText Into thread

this is my code

```html
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Dim startth As Thread
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        startth = New Thread(AddressOf Me.MYTHREAD)
        startth.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub MYTHREAD()
        AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad")
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(TextBox1.Text)
        SendKeys.SendWait("^(v) {Enter}")
        My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(TextBox2.Text)
        SendKeys.SendWait("^(v) {Enter}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception already tells you what you have to do. Set the apartment state of the thread you create:

```
startth = New Thread(AddressOf Me.MYTHREAD)
startth.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
startth.Start()
```

Comment: Thank you very very much sir. that's solved my error

Comment: The clipboard can store many kind of objects, text is just one of them.  Consuming such an object will always involve another thread, typically one in another process.  Such objects therefore must be thread-safe, but very often they are not.  By doing this from an STA thread, you promise to take care of thread-safety requirements so the object is safe.  That requires never blocking the thread and pumping a message loop.  Note that you are not doing this, you lied.  That's dangerous, you'll easily deadlock the program.  But you'll get away with it if it is just text.